# Array Push is not working

Tags: php

I have created a class in following way

```
 class History
    {
      private  $historyArray;
      private $cacheFileNameArray=array();
      public function __construct()
      {
       $this->historyArray=array();
      } 
      public function writeToHistory($query)
      {
       $cacheFileName=$this->getCacheFileName();
       $query=$query.chr(219)."1".chr(219).$cacheFileName;
       array_push($this->historyArray,$query);
       print_r($this->historyArray);
      }
     }
```

Now i have created an object of class History as h,then i'm calling the function writeToHistory() two times with 2 different argument by i wonder that array_push() is not working cause in time of 2nd calling of the function the query should be written in the 1 index of the array but actually the first element of the array is being replaced.Any idea why?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7sEild).

Comment: The code you have posted works as expected, so the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @shapeshifter is right. it's static.

You could even do

```
array_push(History->$historyArray, $query);
```

or

```
array_push(self::$historyArray, $query);
```

or

```
History->$historyArray[] = $query;
```

PHP manual says "If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function." 
(Note from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php);

Answer (score 0):

Your historyArray is static.  Try,

```
array_push(self::$historyArray,$query);
```

Comment: In this case an empty array is being displayed as the result of print_r statement

Comment: @Jack to his credit, initially static was in the code, but the question was edited

Comment: @jack yes it was i was trying even by removing the static,but still its not working

Comment: @AngshuGuha You shouldn't change your question, unless there are serious mistakes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaing historyArray as an array in the constructor?
Also, where is the function '' defined in your class?  if its not defined, that might be causing you trouble...  getCacheFileName();

and, give us an example of what you are passing to your writeToHistory function '$query' variable so that we can mode easily see whats going on please

Change you code to the following:

```
class History
    {
      private  $historyArray = array();
      private $cacheFileNameArray= array();
      public function __construct()
      {

      } 
      public function writeToHistory($query)
      {
       $cacheFileName=$this->getCacheFileName();
       $query=$query.chr(219)."1".chr(219).$cacheFileName;
       array_push($this->historyArray,$query);
       print_r($this->historyArray);
      }
     }
```

Comment: i didnot post that portion of code here the class in enough large to cover the whole page.But i identified the problemetic section so i post that part only

Comment: i'm trying the program with 2 query 1>"select name from table1",2>select id from table1