# PHP - declare a non-static member array?

Tags: php, arrays, class, static

On this question: [Array Push is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847453/array-push-is-not-working)

It seems like the answers are indicating that historyArray is a static array. He did not declare it static; does PHP do this implicitly for all arrays? Is there a way to declare a member array that is not static?

Comment: It is not static, it is case of low quality question and the answers.

Comment: @Danijel Thank you, didn't notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read through the comments, you will see that initially the array was static, but then he edited it.

Comment: @user3475234 you can also look at the question revisions - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14847453/revisions In http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14847453/2 it shows `static` and in http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14847453/4 you can see that the OP removed it.